# PHP Escaping JSON string for CSV export

Tags: php, json, csv, escaping, export-to-csv

I have an array where one of the elements value is a long JSON string

```
foreach ( $results as $data ) {
    // Put the data into the stream
    fputcsv($fh, $data);
}
```

I need a way to escape the JSON string because currently in my CSV export the backslashes in the JSON string are starting new columns

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so by using

```
foreach ( $results as $data ) {
    if(is_array(json_decode($data,true))) continue ;
    fputcsv($fh, $data);
}
```

UPDATE from the last comment ::

Looks like your $data has an array instead of JSON so in this case you can just do

```
foreach ( $results as $data ) {
        if(is_array($data)) continue ;
        fputcsv($fh, $data);
    }
```

AND combining both we can have following where it will escape both JSON and ARRAY

```
foreach ( $results as $data ) {
        if(is_array($data)) continue ;
        if(is_array(json_decode($data,true))) continue ;
        fputcsv($fh, $data);
    }
```

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Also you need to escape double quotes(") by replacing them with 2 double quotes(""). Unless it will start a new column.

Comment: Looks like your $data is an array instead of json if so then u can just use is_array($data)

Comment: Little more explanation with a small code will be more clear to provide answers.

Comment: It is the commas that are causing the problems, the double quotes are ok